# codeigniter php code on xampp works but not on ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code that works perfectly on my local xampp (PHP 5.5.24) but gives error on ubuntu (PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14):

**Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in **/var/www/html/maybright/application/views/admin/components/edit_user.php** on line **179**

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message:  syntax error, unexpected '}'

Filename: components/edit_user.php

Line Number: 179

```
<p>Backtrace:</p>
```

I know it is parse error, so I am attaching the file as well. The controller has this

```
$userDetails = $this->maybright->GetUserDetails($user_id);
    $userDetails = json_decode(json_encode($userDetails), FALSE);
    $content['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $content['User_details'] = $userDetails->response;
    $content['subview']="edit_user";
    $this->load->view('admin/_main_layout', $content);
```

The view is in gist at https://gist.github.com/vishwakarma09/27fc2ca1ec33d8eca05d47c878141a32
you can view it as raw and open in notepad++ for proper indentation.

$userDetails is this json response:

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","id":25,"message":null,"responseSize":1,"response":{"id":25,"hash":null,"name":"Arindam Nath","firstName":null,"middleName":null,"lastName":null,"email":"strider2023@gmail.com","phoneNumber":"9874381131","accountType":"USER","gender":"MALE","dob":630143205000,"maritalStatus":"SINGLE","workStatus":"SALARIED","residentialStatus":"RENTAL","deviceData":null,"userImage":"https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/mbv-pokket\/user-images\/user_profile_25_userImage_1459410437667.jpg","referralCode":null,"fatherName":"Aroon Nath","gcmId":null,"roleType":"LEND","rating":null,"defaults":null,"userLocationDatas":[{"id":70,"userId":25,"address":"House No. 34, Chooliemedu","city":"Chennai","state":"Tamil Nadu","country":"India","pincode":600034,"type":"HOME","isVerified":true},{"id":50,"userId":25,"address":"Chatterjee Bagan","city":"Hooghly","state":"West Bengal","country":"India","pincode":712102,"type":"CURRENT","isVerified":true},{"id":49,"userId":25,"address":"Chatterjee Bagan, ","city":"Hooghly","state":"West Bengal","country":"India","pincode":712102,"type":"HOME","isVerified":true}],"userKYCDatas":[{"id":12,"userId":25,"type":"PASSPORT","kycId":"ASD6Q133","imageUrl":"https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/mbv-pokket\/user-images\/user_kyc_25_kycImg_1459526858473.jpg","isVerified":true},{"id":10,"userId":25,"type":"PAN","kycId":"AHIPN123456","imageUrl":"https:\/\/s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/mbv-pokket\/user-images\/user_kyc_25_kycImg_1458574318698.jpg","isVerified":true}],"userEducationDatas":[{"id":11,"userId":25,"institutionName":"ICAT","degreeType":"BACHELORS","degreeCategoryName":"Game Programming","description":"Game programming","startDate":1187019048000,"endDate":1280158262000,"city":"Chennai","country":"India","state":"Tamil Nadu","pincode":600034,"score":null,"reportUrl":null,"isVerified":true}]}}
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated controller view and current deployed URL in comments. Please check.

Comment: there isnt any php in that file

Comment: there is no parse error in this file: https://gist.github.com/vishwakarma09/27fc2ca1ec33d8eca05d47c878141a32

Comment: @devpro thanks for checking and I see the same, but on server it gives parse error. Any ideas? Let me make another copy and update you with link so you can see on server. Give me some time as I will bypass any login.

Comment: @DevDonkey please see the raw gist, normally it is not showing PHP code

Comment: I cant find anything wrong in the raw gist, are you 100% this is the right file?

Comment: than terminate all php lines with semi colon

Comment: Hi,

I made separate CI controller with view and controller for issue.

Links to [controller][1] and [view][2] in gist. This is deployed at http://52.33.136.205/ci_test/


  [1]: https://gist.github.com/vishwakarma09/1d30a4e9b5cbb46af6ad317104846c5c
  [2]: https://gist.github.com/vishwakarma09/6aac6a4b3a4fd4b99a0b749b4b71d703

Comment: I'd guess it's because the `}` in question closes an 'if() {` on line 123, which is opened by short tags i.e. `<?` rather than `<?php`, and the Ubuntu server doesn't allow short tags.  It's therefore parsing that as HTML output, and seeing the `}` as actual PHP which shouldn't be there

Comment: @gabe3886 this solved issue. The issue was one <? php short tag, which was not supported on server. Hats off to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my comment as an answer as it helped fix the issue:

The problem is that the close bracket in question is the close to an opening if-statement on line 123.  This statement is opened by the following code:

```
<? if(isset($User_details->userLocationDatas)){ ?>
```

This is using the PHP short tags option (doesn't start `<?php`)  The windows machine the development is taking place on allows this, but the Ubuntu server doesn't.  As a result, the opening if statement is treated as HTML by the server, and the correctly formed `<?php }?>` is seen as not needed; hence the error.

There's a couple of ways I can think of to help avoid this in future:

- Never use short tags for PHP in your code.  Either use `<?php` or `<?=` as appropriate.  The former is more readable and widely used
- Where possible, develop on an environment which is configured the same (or as close as possible) to the environment it is going to be deployed on, so these issues are caught early.